# Code Index API / Code Index Client Applications permissions requested in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

A few months ago Visual Studio started popping up a permissions request for "Code Index Client Applications" from "Code Index API".

[image]

If I click on the "Report it here" link, I'm taken to another page that says it is from "AME.GBL".

[image]

I don't know what this is, so I always hit cancel.  I have not noticed any kind of problems with not granting it what it wants, and I'm getting tired of it asking, so I'd like to try and remove whatever it is that is asking.  I've tried disabling all my extensions, but it still asks.  I have looked in the Visual Studio Installer's "Individual components" and also my Windows "Apps & features", but there is nothing with these names listed there.  I have looked online but can't find anything about it.

Does anyone know what this is or how to get rid of it (or is there some reason why I should grant it permission)?

Comment: related dev community page: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Credential-detection-broken-symptom:-R/10056109

Answer (score 10):

The dialog that pops up has changed slightly and I think it gives the answer:

[image]

You can read about Rich Code Navigation [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/rich-code-navigation/) or see a demo of it (primarily in Visual Studio Code) [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2018/12/04/rich-navigation).  Note that the second link is from 2018, so in one form or another, this has been around for some time, but perhaps it has been off by default until a recent update?
At any rate, if you choose to disable Rich Code Navigation, you can do that under

Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Preview features

[image]

I did that and the permissions request dialog went away.